# How to use a module 'fs' in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

I want to import JSON data from my local repository.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var data = fs.readFileSync('./profile.json', 'utf8');
console.log(data);

...
```

However Cypress occurs this error:

[image]

Here is my package.json from my cypress project.

```
{
  "name": "cypress_test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npx cypress run",
    "clean-reports": "rm -rf cypress/reports",
    "merge-report": "npx mochawesome-merge --reportDir cypress/reports/separate-reports cypress/reports/full_report.json",
    "generate-report": "npx mochawesome-report-generator --reportDir cypress/reports cypress/reports/full_report.json",
    "after:tests": "npm run merge-report; npm run generate-report",
    "cypress": "npm run clean-reports; npm run test; npm run after:tests"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "type": "module",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^5.4.1",
    "cypress": "^4.11.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "mocha": "5.2.0",
    "mochawesome": "4.1.0",
    "mochawesome-merge": "2.0.1",
    "mochawesome-report-generator": "4.0.1",
    "papaparse": "^5.2.0",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.7",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1"
  }
}
```

I don't want to use cy.fixture because I need to use data from json in my 'it test discription'. For example, I want to make tests like this.

```
it (datas.data, ()=>{
   ...
})
```

Comment: If you want to use node commands like `fs.readFileSync` within a Cypress test you must put them in a task, see first example in [the docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task.html#Examples). But why do you not use `cy.fixture()`?

Comment: agree with @MarionMorrison , why are u not using fixtures here ?

Comment: @MarionMorrison as far as I know fixture's data can only be accessed in testing area(it, specify). I wanted to use data in the title of each tests. For example, it('this test is'+data.test_name, () => ...).

Comment: You can run `cy.fixture()` in a `before()` at the top of the spec.

Comment: There is also [cy.readFile()](https://example.cypress.io/commands/files#readfile), the difference is `cy.fixture()` will parse the JSON to an object but `cy.readFile()` will give you the file contents as a string (same as `fs.readFileSync()` if used in a task).

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to load your `profile.json` with the require statement.

```
const data = require('profile.json');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've tried 'require' (var file = 'profile.json' const datas = require('./'+file)) but apparently 'require' doesn't support string variable. By using switch conditional statement, I think I could import Json dynamically, but this is kind of silly.

Comment: @loone96 `require('./'+file)` is valid syntax in node.js and should work. It has always worked for me

Comment: Should `require()` from a relative path, otherwise it is looking in node_modules.

Comment: To add my own findings - there seems to be some form of static analysis happening on the `require` calls within Cypress. If the require argument starts with a string literal (including a template string) then Cypress tries to preload all of that initial string (directory) into memory. If it is a variable (even a constant variable declared as a literal string), then Cypress seems to preload nothing and the module is not available in the browser.

Answer (score 4):

To use fs, or various other Node modules, you *must* put it in a plugin. From https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests#Plugins-file:

> While the Cypress tests execute in the browser, the plugins file runs in the background Node process, giving your tests the ability to access the file system and the rest of the operating system by calling the `cy.task()` command

This is alluded to in the comments above, but I missed it there so I want to make it clear.

Comment: This answer is not actually helpful.  _How_ do I "put it in a plugin"?  _How_ do I invoke such functions after that?

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier I was able to implement fs logic after reviewing this https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task#Read-a-file-that-might-not-exist. Basically, you have to work with fs in the plugins/index.html file. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

This is quite an old thread, but there is now the possibility to use the package [cypress-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-fs) (which I am the author of) like so:

```
cy.fsReadFile(path, options)
```

The package is internally using the fs module, it requires you to register some support file in your `cypress.config.ts`. Steps to do so are included in the documentation.